# do not get an ISO image when downloading latest ubuntu 32/64 bit what am I doing wrong

Tags: iso

have downloaded and then unzipped ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS on 8/22/14 to my windows 7 desktop. 
I get lots of folders and files after unzipping, but can not figure out how to create the iso image. My goal is to do so on a USB stick, but haven't been able to get to that step, wah!

Comment: From where and how did you downloaded Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Comment: You shouldn't unzip it. http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

Comment: Windows 7 may be hiding the file extensions by default. [Show file extensions.](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/show-hide-file-name-extensions#show-hide-file-name-extensions=windows-7) Then you will see the downloaded file has extension `.iso`. Use the file "as is" [according to the official instructions.](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)

Comment: to Add some info to @user68186 if you open up windows explorer and browse to the location you downloaded the ISO file. you can hit the "alt" key on your keyboard and you should see a menu appear at the top of the window. Click tools, then folder options. In the New Windows click the view tab and in the list of check boxes uncheck the box next to "Hide extensions of known file types"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I uninstalled winrar which was prompting me to unzip it, and got my ISO image, put it on pen drive and have it installed on my win 7 machine. Love it!
Figured this out by using another windows 7 machine that did not have winrar installed.
Yay!